# Snakemake: unknown output/input files after splitting by chromosome

Tags: bioinformatics, snakemake, vpython, vcf-variant-call-format, vcftools

To speed up a certain snakemake step I would like to:

- split my bamfile per chromosome using
  `bamtools split -in sample.bam --reference`
  this results in files named as `sample.REF_{chromosome}.bam`
- perform variant calling on each resulting in e.g. `sample.REF_{chromosome}.vcf`
- recombine the obtained vcf files using vcf-concat (VCFtools) using
  `vcf-concat file1.vcf file2.vcf file3.vcf > sample.vcf`

The problem is that I don't know a priori which chromosomes may be in my bam file. So I cannot specify accurately the output of `bamtools split`. Furthermore, I'm not sure how to make the input of `vcf-concat` to take all vcf files.

I thought of using a samples.fofn and do something like

```
rule split_bam:
    input:
        bam = "alignment/{sample}.bam",
        pattern = "alignment/{sample}.REF_"
    output:
        alignment/anon.splitbams.fofn
    log:
        "logs/bamtools_split/{sample}.log"
    shell:
        "bamtools split -in {input.bam} -reference && \
         ls alignment/{input.pattern}*.bam | sed 's/.bam/.vcf/' > {output}"
```

And use the same `fofn` for concatenating the obtained vcf files. But this feels like a very awkward hack and I'd appreciate your suggestions.

---

EDIT 20180409

As suggested by @jeeyem I tried the `dynamic()` functions, but I can't figure it out.

My complete snakefile is on [GitHub](https://github.com/wdecoster/nano-snakemake/blob/master/SV-nanopore.smk), the dynamic part is at [lines 99-133](https://github.com/wdecoster/nano-snakemake/blob/master/SV-nanopore.smk#L99).

The error I get is:

`InputFunctionException in line 44 of /home/wdecoster/DR34/SV-nanopore.smk:
KeyError: 'anon___snakemake_dynamic'
Wildcards:
sample=anon___snakemake_dynamic`

(with `anon` an anonymized {sample} identifier)

Running with --debug-dag gives (last parts before erroring):

`candidate job cat_vcfs
    wildcards: sample=anon
candidate job nanosv
    wildcards: sample=anon___snakemake_dynamic, chromosome=_
candidate job samtools_index
    wildcards: aligner=split_ngmlr, sample=anon___snakemake_dynamic.REF__
candidate job split_bam
    wildcards: sample=anon___snakemake_dynamic, chromosome=_
InputFunctionException in line 44 of /home/wdecoster/DR34/SV-nanopore.smk:
KeyError: 'anon___snakemake_dynamic'
Wildcards:
sample=anon___snakemake_dynamic`

Which shows that the wildcard is misinterpreted?

---

Cheers,
Wouter

Comment: Have you looked into `dynamic` feature that snakemake [offers](http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#dynamic-files)?

Comment: @JeeYem it looks like that might do the trick, I'll try. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @JeeYem (after a week of holidays) I have attempted your suggestion, but I can't figure it out. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can lookup the chromosome names from the bam header, or a corresponding `.fai` file for the used reference. This can be done at the beginning of your Snakefile. Then, you can use `expand("alignment/{{sample}}.REF_{chromosome}.bam", chromosome=chromosomes)` to define the output files of that rule. No need to use dynamic.

Comment: Say I want to automate this procedure for any BAM file.  My current
solution uses checkpoints (cool feature, btw !), where I do variant
calling based on the per-chromosome BAM files which appear after the
split -- like in the clustering example.  Only, in this case, _I know_
somehow, before the split (albeit, not at the initial evaluation of
the DAG) how many BAM files will appear, _e.g._, from the `.fai` file.
So I have the inkling that there is a simpler solution, but I do not
know enough to be sure.  Thanks in advance !