# A curious case of snakemake

Tags: snakemake

I have a similar goal as in [Snakemake: unknown output/input files after splitting by chromosome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49574969/snakemake-unknown-output-input-files-after-splitting-by-chromosome) , however, as pointed out, I do know in advance that I have *e.g.*, 5 chromosomes in my `sample.bam` file.  Using as a toy example:

```
$ cat sample.bam 
chromosome 1
chromosome 2
chromosome 3
chromosome 4
chromosome 5
```

I wish to "split" this bam file, and then do a bunch of *per chromosome* downstream jobs on the resulting chromosomes.  The simplest solution I could conjure up was:

```
chromosomes = '1 2 3 4 5'.split()

rule master :
    input :
        expand('sample.REF_{chromosome}.bam',
            chromosome = chromosomes)


rule chromosome :
    output :
        touch('sample.REF_{chromosome}.bam')

    input : 'split.done'


rule split_bam :
    output :
        touch('split.done')

    input : 'sample.bam'

    run :
        print('splitting bam..')
        chromosome = 1
        for line in open(input[0]) :
            outfile = 'sample.REF_{}.bam'.format(chromosome)
            print(line, end = '', file = open(outfile, 'w'))
            chromosome += 1
```

results in empty `sample_REF_{chromosome}.bam` files.  I understand why this happens, and indeed snakemake even warns, *e.g.*,

```
Warning: the following output files of rule chromosome were not present when the DAG was created:
{'sample.REF_3.bam'}
Touching output file sample.REF_3.bam.
```

that is, these files were not in the DAG to begin with, and snakemake touches them with empty versions, erasing what *was* put there.  I guess I am surprised by this behavior, and wonder if there is a good reason for this.  Note that this behavior is not limited to snakemake's `touch()`, since, should I replace `touch('sample.REF_{chromosome}.bam')` with simply `'sample.REF_{chromosome}.bam'`, and then have a `shell :`touch {output}`, I get the same result.  Now, of course, I have found a perfectly acceptable workaround:

```
chromosomes = '1 2 3 4 5'.split()

rule master :
    input :
        expand('sample.REF_{chromosome}.bam',
            chromosome = chromosomes)


rule chromosome :
    output : 'sample.REF_{chromosome}.bam'

    input : 'split_dir'

    shell : 'mv {input}/{output} {output}'


rule split_bam :
    output :
        temp(directory('split_dir'))

    input : 'sample.bam'

    run :
        print('splitting bam..')
        shell('mkdir {output}')
        chromosome = 1
        for line in open(input[0]) :
            outfile = '{}/sample.REF_{}.bam'.format(output[0], chromosome)
            print(line, end = '', file = open(outfile, 'w'))
            chromosome += 1
```

but I am surprised I have to go though these gymnastics for a seemingly simple task.  For this reason, I wonder if there is a better design, or if I am not asking the right question.  Any advice/ideas are most welcome.

Comment: Please take some time to format your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think your example is a bit contrived for a couple of reasons. The rule `split_bam` already produces the final output `sample.REF_{chromosome}.bam`. Also, the rule `master` uses the chromosomes taken from the variable `chromosomes` whereas the rule `split_bam` iterates through the bam file to get the chromosomes.

My impression is that what you want could be something like:

```
chromosomes= '1 2 3 4 5'.split()

rule master:
    input:
        expand('sample.REF_{chromosome}.bam',
            chromosome = chromosomes)

rule split_bam :
    input:
        'sample.bam'
    output:
        expand('sample.split.{chromosome}.bam', chromosome= chromosomes)
    run:
        print('splitting bam..')
        for chromosome in chromosomes:
            outfile = 'sample.split.{}.bam'.format(chromosome)
            print(chromosome, end = '', file = open(outfile, 'w'))

rule chromosome:
    input:
        'sample.split.{chromosome}.bam'
    output:
        touch('sample.REF_{chromosome}.bam')
```